# i am trying to disable a button in my html form but i dont know what went wrong can some one help me

Tags: javascript, html

I am creating a password change page. I am trying to disable the submit button when the two passwords do not match. I don't know what went wrong can some one explain to me?

```
<form role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Existing Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Existing Password" required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>New Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="npassword" type="password" placeholder="New Password" id="npassword" onchange='check_pass();' required/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Confirm New Password</label>
        <input class="form-control" name="cnpassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm New Password" id="cnpassword " onchange='check_pass();' required/>
    </div>
    <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" disabled>Submit </button>
    <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
    <script>
        function check_pass() {
            if (document.getElementById('npassword').value == document.getElementById('cnpassword').value) {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
            } else {
                document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
            }
        }
    </script>
</form>
```

Comment: You need to explain more about what is not working. Are there any error messages? Is something expected not happening?

Comment: Thank you andrew  for editing my code iam trying to disable my submit button when the npassword and cnpassword doesn't match anyway thanks for the help dude.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a space in cnpassword's id.

```html
<form role="form">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Existing Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Existing Password" required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>New Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="npassword" type="password" placeholder="New Password" id="npassword" onchange='check_pass();' required/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Confirm New Password</label>
    <input class="form-control" name="cnpassword" type="password" placeholder="Confirm New Password" id="cnpassword" onchange='check_pass();' required/>
  </div>
  <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-default" id="submit" disabled>Submit </button>
  <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Reset Button</button>
  <script>
    function check_pass() {
      if (document.getElementById('npassword').value == document.getElementById('cnpassword').value) {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = false;
      } else {
        document.getElementById('submit').disabled = true;
      }
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Scath i was scribbling around this code not realizing this silly mistake. You saved my day.